# mysql event scheduler displays error: 'database not selected'

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I apologize if this question seems mundane, but I couldn't find a suitable answer on the web. It's my first time working with event scheduler in phpmyadmin and I think I've got the syntax down:

```
CREATE EVENT `zero_my_column`
ON SCHEDULE EVERY
    1 MINUTE STARTS '2017-07-21 19:02:00'
DO BEGIN
UPDATE
    `runners`.`run`
SET
    `weekly_total` = 0
WHERE
    `weekly_total` <> 0
END;
```

However, when I run this query in my localhost/phpmyadmin page I get the following error: `#1046 - No database selected`. `runners` is my database and `run` is my table. I am trying to reset the `weekly_total` column to zero. I'm wondering if the error arises because I need to enter validation to access the database, but I'm unsure.  Any tips/hints are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out:

To create an event

```
Go into phpmyadmin
go to the database you will schedule the event for 
click on Events tab
Then enter the script to schedule the event
```